# Bouncy Castle lib generates "java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't encode public key"

Tags: java, cryptography, bouncycastle

I'm trying to use bouncy castle lib either **bcprov-jdk15-136.jar** or **bcprov-jdk16-140.jar**

**I have the following RSA Private Key:**

generateRSAKeyPair - RSA Private Key, iccKeypair cyphered under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

**And have the following RSA Public Key:**

generateRSAKeyPair - RSA Public Key, iccKeypair cyphered under KEK BDBC2FC40FBA580EFB9A9AC346C10FCE6F4C72BD6D79D2039807ABAB644D9F49F5EC06152B78A9C4D7468D6A82F3FEBFF0ABC7EE166C9FBC2A10DB1FE1AA4C66D6B94C871BEC97CE818EE03DDBFB55F5CC9E050E7BB7202EEBD6471172491F2EA22B83D62A747EE6677DBB7CFDA2ED6B0C3EE10D550760E20654A0421133778B

**whenever I'm trying to run the following code:**

```
X500Principal subject = new X500Principal("CN=Test V3 Certificate");
PKCS10CertificationRequest kpGen = new PKCS10CertificationRequest("SHA1withRSA", subject, publicKey, null, privateKey);
```

I keep getting

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: can't encode public key
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.PKCS10CertificationRequest.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.PKCS10CertificationRequest.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.gemalto.nrs.test.KmsTest.generatePCK10(KmsTest.java:148)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:39)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:518)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1052)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.main(JUnitTestRunner.java:906)
```

**and when I try to debug the code sometimes I get**

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.bouncycastle.asn1.DERApplicationSpecific cannot be cast to org.bouncycastle.asn1.ASN1Sequence
at org.bouncycastle.jce.PKCS10CertificationRequest.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.bouncycastle.jce.PKCS10CertificationRequest.<init>(Unknown Source)
at com.gemalto.nrs.test.KmsTest.generatePCK10(KmsTest.java:148)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at junit.framework.JUnit4TestAdapter.run(JUnit4TestAdapter.java:39)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.run(JUnitTestRunner.java:518)
at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.optional.junit.JUnitTestRunner.launch(JUnitTestRunner.java:1052)
```

Comment: It looks like you are just calling random methods and hoping something good will happen. It won't, so don't do that. The "iccKeypair cyphered under KEK" is your clue that you have something special. Perhaps those are from some hardware token?

Comment: KEK means Key Encryption Key, so the information you have is encrypted with a (symmetric) key. You need to decrypt the keys before you can use them.

Comment: the generated public and private keys was jus DER and it was not ASN1

Answer (score 0):

the generated public and private keys was just DER and it was not ASN1

so I have to get the ASN1 for each of them before using them and this was the root cause of this problem.

the following calls solve the problem:

```
    PublicKey publicKey = RSAtoX509Key.getPublicKey(PUBLIC_KEY.getBytes(), RSA_EXPONENT, "BC");
    PrivateKey privateKey = RSAtoX509Key.getPrivateKey(PRIVATE_KEY.getBytes(), RSA_EXPONENT, "BC");

    public static PublicKey getPublicKey(byte[] modulus, byte[] exponent, String provider) {
        PublicKey publicKey = null;
        try {
            RSAPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(1, modulus), new BigInteger(1, exponent));
            KeyFactory keyFactory = null;
            if(provider != null && !provider.isEmpty()) {
                keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA", provider);
            } else {
                keyFactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            }

            publicKey = keyFactory.generatePublic(pubKeySpec);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            logger.error(ex.getMessage());
            return null;
        }

        return publicKey;
    }
```

offcourse the keys were encrypted using a KEK key but this is another issue and is not related to the above Exception.